# MySQL 5.6 upgrade - reducing code changes / developer burden

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, upgrade

Does anyone know the key things that should be done when moving to MySQL 5.6 to reduce the amount of code changes required? I found that new installations of it have `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` set for `sql_mode` by default.

I plan to go through the release notes and upgrade guides on the MySQL site in more depth but during a past upgrade which was only a point-release change, there was a backwards incompatible change that wasn't called out in the release notes

I wanted to see if anyone had anything noteworthy to mention from experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran headlong into this one 6 months

The only sane thing you can do is the following two steps

## STEP 01

Add this to my.cnf under the `[mysqld]` group header

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ''
```

## STEP 02

Login as `root@localhost` and run this

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Restarting mysql is not required.

## STEP 03 (Optional)

**STEP 02** only affects incoming connections after the change. You may have to kill all current DB Connections. Let the app reconnect and it will begin with sql_mode as blank. While restarting mysql is not needed for incoming connections, you could just run `service mysql restart` instead of custom scripting the killing of DB Connections.

If you want to custom script the killing of your connections, please see some of my past posts for exmaples on how to kill many connections:

- `May 10, 2011` : [kill all queries - MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/kill-all-queries-mysql/2637#2637)
- `Jun 05, 2013` : [Too Many database connections on Amazon RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43899/too-many-database-connections-on-amazon-rds/43902#43902)
- `Dec 25, 2013` : [Mysql. Block/disconnect slow queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/mysql-block-disconnect-slow-queries/55588#55588)

## STEP 04 (Optional, Last Resort)

If you would like to make code changes, the only change would be to run

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

as the first command for the connection. Then, you could run your regular queries thereafter.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

**NOTE #1** : The first two steps are more than enough for your app if you close your connection right after running your query. If your connections are persistent, then you will need STEP 03.

**NOTE #2** : If you are not allowed to change the configuration, you could skip **STEP 01** and **STEP 02** and just run **STEP 03** and **STEP 04**.

Comment: Those are some good options for dealing with sql_mode. I was planning to just deal with sql_mode via my.cnf, but I was interested in anything else you or others have encountered with transitioning to 5.6. Thanks!

Comment: These were the actual steps I performed for a client months ago in dev and production. Other than having to explicitly set sql_mode to a blank string to make backward compatible with code that worked in MySQL 5.5 now operating in MySQL 5.6, there isn't anything else.